# Run all Tests in Directory Using Testoob

Tags: python, testing, frameworks

I'm looking for a Python testing framework that would allow me to type one command and run all tests in a certain directory. I've been using Testoob and, so far, I've been able to figure out how to run all the tests in a suite. But I can't figure out how to run an entire directory of test suites. Is this even possible with Testoob? Is there another framework that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[`nose`](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/1.0.0/) lets you do precisely that.

```
cd path/to/project
nosetests
```